# HQL order by expression

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, hql

I have two persistent classes, `Comment` and `Vote`. A `Comment` can be associated with many `Vote`s and there is a `@OneToMany` - `@ManyToOne` relationship between them that's working correctly. What I'm trying to do is to sort the comments by most upvotes. A `Vote` is an upvote if `Vote.up` column is `1` and downvote if `Vote.up` is `0`. I'm trying to work out their difference

So far this is my HQL but it's not working

```
select c from Comment c
order by (
    (select count(*) from c.votes v where v.up = 1) 
    - (select count(*) from c.votes v where v.up = 0)
) desc
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Any chance you could change the data model so that `Vote.up = -1` would identify a downvote? This would make it possible to use `sum()` for calculating the difference.

Comment: Yes I can do that, what would it look like then?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with HQL (or your table relations) but in SQL, you could do an aggregation (`GROUP BY`) of comments from the `Vote` table. something like this: `SELECT commentid, sum(up) FROM Vote GROUP BY commentid ORDER BY sum(up) desc`.

Comment: It probably won't work directly because it uses DB tables instead of entities. If you could post the entity (or DB table) descriptions for `Comment` and `Vote`, you might get better answers.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: You can simplify (and probably speed up) the subselects by combining them in one: select sum((v.up*2)-1) ...

Comment: This should be a new feature for JPA. I've just created one here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jpa-api/issues/301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HQL doesn't support such a syntax, so you'll have to use a native query for this:

```
List<Comment> comments = (List<Comment>) session.createSQLQuery(
        "select * " +
        "from Comment " +
        "where id in (   " +
        "    select comment_id " +
        "    from (     " +
        "        select        " +
        "            c.id as comment_id,        " +
        "            SUM(CASE WHEN v.up=1 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS vote_count     " +
        "        from Comment c     " +
        "        left join Votes v on c.id = v.comment_id     " +
        "        group by comment_id     " +
        "        order by vote_count desc   " +
        "    ) c_v " +
        ") c_id"
).addEntity(Comment.class).list();
```

Comment: I'll try this later today. Thanks a lot Vlad!

Comment: I'm getting this :/
`2015-06-18 19:46:17 WARN  JDBCExceptionReporter:100 - SQL Error: 1241, SQLState: 21000
2015-06-18 19:46:17 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
`

Comment: I managed to get it working by tweaking it a bit but didn't have to change much, only problem I had was the above error, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this sql example:

```
FROM Employee E WHERE E.id > 10 " +
         "ORDER BY E.firstName DESC, E.salary DESC
```

Its an example of a hql sentence. 
Are you sure that your sentence works fine?

Comment: Sorry, i mean before hql example not sql